# Screen Resizing Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
function sizeChange() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var main = document.getElementById('main');
    var content = document.getElementById('content');
    var h = window.innerHeight;
    container.style.height = h;
    main.style.height = h*.9;
    content.style.height = (h*.9)*.9;
}

document.addEventListener("resize", sizeChange);
```

I'm trying to manipulate the items in my html so the height of the container is constantly the height of the window and that when it's scaled, the height of the container scales. I have it set up so it gets the ID of each element it's going to manipulate and then adjusts by a % of what I want it to be. Does anyone have any feedback on why this is happening?

Comment: You don't actually say what is going wrong in your post.  I took a guess below

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I posted it in such haste. For some reason the container's height isn't adjusting and just stays at the height it's initially assigned.

Answer (score 0):

I would think most of what you are doing could be done with CSS.  If you want to stick with JS, then you need to add units to your values.  So change the code to something like

```
container.style.height = h+"px";
main.style.height = Math.floor(h*.9)+"px";
content.style.height = Math.floor((h*.9)*.9)+"px";
```